# What's the purpose of directory /private/var/db/receipts?

Tags: macos

I searched and found several steps to remove the redundant files. 
Then I found in /private/var/db/receipts there are many config like files, Anyone know the purpose if this directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files in `/private/var/db/receipts` are...well...receipts for packages/apps you have installed on your Mac. They list what was installed and when. The Plists also include version information. For example heres an example of my plist for Xcode (`com.apple.pkg.Xcode.plist`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>InstallDate</key>
    <date>2018-06-05T18:36:40Z</date>
    <key>InstallPrefixPath</key>
    <string>/</string>
    <key>InstallProcessName</key>
    <string>storedownloadd</string>
    <key>PackageFileName</key>
    <string>Xcode.pkg</string>
    <key>PackageIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.pkg.Xcode</string>
    <key>PackageVersion</key>
    <string>9.4.0.0.1.1526532315</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**I don't think it has anything to do with MySQL.**

Comment: Yes, it's nothing to do with MySQL. I will remove this in the question.

I found even after I removing the software on my mac, the related plist and "receipts" files still remains here. Is it safe to remove them? @JBis

Comment: @YiliangTang Well you still have a receipt after using the item you buy. It should be safe to remove them, especially since you removed the software associated with them. To be sure I would just but them in trash. Use your comp for a couple of days and if there are no issues then you can empty trash.  But I don't really think removal is necessary. Lastly, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as answers and upvote so other users with similar/same issues will be able to find it easier. Thanks!